# Is skydiving from 4km dangerous for people who suffer from ear pain in planes?

Tags: ear, pressure, barotrauma, air-pressure

Sometimes, specially if I have nasal congestion, because of a cold or hayfever, I have ear pain when landing. I also had problems with equalizing the one time I did scuba diving, last year.

Some friends of mine are going to try skydiving and I'm thinking of joining them, but I'm worried about ear pain (or ear injuries). They'll jump from 4km. I understand the pressure difference is not as bad as when a plane comes down from 8-10km, but on the other hand, it'd be much faster.

Is this dangerous for someone like me?